Issue with global variable update in Drools
`I am new to drools, need help
Java File:
kieSession.insert(csaResponseRootDTO);
kieSession.fireAllRules();
System.out.println(kieSession.getGlobal("count")); ==> This is printing as null
kieSession.dispose();

DRL File:
rule "Calculate the score" 

when 
$p : DTO() $section : SectionsDTO($sectionName : sectionName, sectionName == "XX") from
$p.sectionsList

$subSection : SubSectionsDTO($subSectionName : subSectionName, subSectionName == "YY") from    $section.subSectionsList

$question : QuestionDTO($questionId : questionId, questionId == "ZZ") from $subSection.questionsList

$questionOption : OptionsDTO($key : key, $selected : selected) from $question.questionnaireOptions

if($key == "yes" && $selected == true) do[yes]
else if($key == "no" && $selected == true) do[no]
    
then
then[yes]
//Accumulate the option values based on the user selected input
double $calc = ConfigContextInitiator.checkBalances(reportConfig, $sectionName,   $subSectionName, $questionId, $key);
System.out.println($calc); // It is printing correctly
kcontext.getKieRuntime().setGlobal("count", $calc);
         
then[no]
double $calc2 = ConfigContextInitiator.checkBalances(reportConfig, $sectionName, $subSectionName, $questionId, $key);
System.out.println($calc2); // It is printing correctly
kcontext.getKieRuntime().setGlobal("count", $calc2);
        
end

** And also it will be great if someone provide the sample working code how to update the global variable in the subsequent rules`

This is not how you use globals.
You use globals by setting an object at the time you call the rules, then updating its state while your rules are executing. Globals are not primitives.
And you really should never be mucking around with the kcontext in the rules themselves.
List<String> fruits = new ArrayList<>();

KieSession session = ruleBase.newStatefulSession();
session.insert(...); // insert data
session.setGlobal( "fruits", fruits);
session.fireAllRules();

System.out.println(fruits); // will now reflect any changes made to it in the rules

global List fruits

rule "On sale fruits"
when
  Cart( $items: items != null )
  Item( onSale == true,
        type == ItemType.FRUIT,
        $name: name ) from $items
then
  fruits.add($name);
  // do other stuff with on-sale fruits
end

Assuming the Cart you pass into working memory  looks like this:
Cart {
  items: [
    Item{ name: "banana", type: ItemType.FRUIT, onSale: true },
    Item{ name: "blueberry", type: ItemType.FRUIT, onSale: false },
    Item{ name: "kiwi", type: ItemType.FRUIT, onSale: true },
    Item{ name: "artichoke", type: ItemType.VEGETABLE, onSale: true },
    Item{ name: "broccoli", type: ItemType.VEGETABLE, onSale: true }
  ]
}

You would expect the Java code (System.out.println(fruits)) to print (in some order): banana, kiwi.

If you really want to preserve whatever "$count" is, you can use something like an AtomicDouble. Or create some sort of business object to track side effects and set that as a global. Generally speaking this is the very "old-fashioned" way of getting results out of rules -- this is how we'd do things back in Drools 5.0 times.
These days you'd usually do something in your rules to something in working memory that has state, and track side effects that way. Eg. pass some sort of Balances object into working memory when you fire the rules and modify that directly. That would allow you to also write rules that key off of changes to those values. (since you cannot write rules that key off of values or changes to globals.)
